# Add Custom field to woocommerce product for an specific category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add a custom field "Color" to my woocommerce orders but this custom field has to be in a few specific categories, let's say category "ballons", so the code inside functions.php is this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button','wdm_add_custom_fields');

                      /**
                      * Adds custom field for Product
                      * @return [type] [description]
                      */
    function wdm_add_custom_fields()
       {

          global $product;
          ob_start();

          $terms = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );

          // Loop through term objects
            foreach( $terms as $term ) {
              if ( "ballons" === $term->slug ) {
        ?>
          <div class="wdm-custom-fields">
            <label>Color </label>
             <select type="text" name="wdm_name">     
                <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                <option value="red">Rojo</option>
                <option value="green">Green</option>      
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="clear"></div>
    <br>
    
    <?php 
      //  break; // The term match, we stop the loop.
        }
       }        
      ?>
```

The select box appears in all products , seems like the above code is not restricting the select box to the specific category, any help would be appreciate it

Comment: Have you tried looking at the terms: print_r($terms); to see if "ballons" is in the list for each product

Comment: yes, but is not printing anything....

Comment: Its probably because of the output buffer (ob_start()).  Try adding the term as an option, just to test, "<option value=""> <?php echo $term; ?> </option>

Comment: I did but nothing gets printed ,just a blank space

Comment: I would trust @LoicTheAztec and use his answer.  Very knowledgeable gentleman (I'm guessing gender here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use instead the dedicated Wordpress conditional function `has_term()` as follow:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'before_add_to_cart_button_custom_fields');
function before_add_to_cart_button_custom_fields() {
    global $post, $product;

    // Here define your terms (can be terms Ids, slugs or names)
    $terms = array('ballons');

    if ( has_term( $terms, 'product_cat' ) ) {
    ?>
    <div class="wdm-custom-fields">
        <label><?php _e("Color", "woocommerce"); ?></label>
        <select type="text" name="wdm_name">
            <option value="blue"><?php _e("Blue", "woocommerce"); ?></option>
            <option value="red"><?php _e("Rojo", "woocommerce"); ?></option>
            <option value="green"><?php _e("Green", "woocommerce"); ?></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <br>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> You should replace `wdm_name` simply by `color` everywhere in your code

Comment: nice answer, however is not working yet... even with var_dump($terms) it won't print anything

Comment: @ClaudioMartinez Sorry but I have tested that code for real and it works… You can see that on [this test server](https://www.cbleu.net/sites/woolast/product/grooms-t-shirt/) (with last WP / WC versions) for the product category "T shirts". So in your case, there is something wrong somewhere  as the code works just fine (your category "ballons" needs directly to be set for the product, if not the code will not work and you will need something different).